# how to continue processing after exception in python without aborting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a block of code where exception is happening for some records while executing an imported method (pls see below). My goal is NOT to stop execution, but perhaps print (to understand what's wrong with the data) some values when in error and continue. I tried various way to use "try...except", but no luck! Can someone pls take a look and suggest? Many thanks in advance!

code below

```
if student_name not in original_df_names_flat:
    for org in orgs:
        data = calculate(org, data)
    result = imported_module.execute(data) # here's the line where exception happens
    return result

else:
    return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below solution took care of the problem:

```
if student_name not in original_df_names_flat:
    for org in orgs:
        data = calculate(org, data)

    try:
        result = imported_module.execute(data) # here's the line where exception happens
    except exception as e:
        print ("exception happened", e)
        pass
        return data

    return result

else:
    return data
```

the above solution took care of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess an exception can occur in 2 places. So try this. It covers your exception line and the other possibility. So your program should keep running.

Secondly I have adjusted the indentation of the second try clause so the loop processes all data in orgs. To return all results I have added a list 'results'.

```
if student_name not in original_df_names_flat:
    
    results = []
    for org in orgs:
        try:
            data = calculate(org, data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            
        try:
            result = imported_module.execute(data) # here's the line where exception happens
            results.append(result)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        
    return results

else:
    return data
```

Comment: with this, it gives "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment" during run time. This is for the line `return result`.

Comment: That's not strange because on an exception result hasn't been assigned a value. I have added result = None which seems the most logical value.

Comment: Ok; but when exception takes place, it comes out of the execution, without continuing. I tried adding `pass` under `except`, but no luck

Comment: It comes out of the execution because it is already outside the for loop. I have adjusted the code so it preocesses all data in orgs.

Comment: But in that case 'return result' makes no sense because only the last result will be returned. To fix that I added the list 'results' that will be returned.

Comment: returning `data` in case of exception took care of this

Answer (score 0):

```
if student_name not in original_df_names_flat:
    for org in orgs:
        data = calculate(org, data)

    result = None  # May fail to get assigned if error in imported_module
    try:
        result = imported_module.execute(data) # here's the line where exception happens
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'{e}')  # probably better to log the exception

    return result

else:
    return data
```

Comment: actually, it gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` once it tries to continue after exception occurs

Comment: returning `data` in case of exception took care of this

Comment: This indicates that the error was with the orgs being bound to None and not with the imported_module.